# Help with jquery animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using this code to change opacity when user is on and off a picture unfortunately when the user clicks the image the opacity does not stay at 1. Anyone has an answer ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('img#slide').animate({"opacity" : .7})
  $('img#slide').hover(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 1})
  }, function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : .7})

  });                


  $('img#slide').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"opacity" : 1});
  });

});
```

Comment: its important that you include the code right in the question so future searchers can benefit from it, even after pastebin has deleted the paste. I moved it in the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow disable the `mouseleave` animation when the user clicks.

A common approach is to add a class, and have the `mouseleave` check for the existence of the class.

**Test the live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/KnCmR/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('img#slide').animate({ "opacity": .7 })

    .hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 1 })
    }, 
    function () {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass("active") ) {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": .7 });
        }
    })

    .click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want a second click to revert the behavior back to the original, use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`:

```
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
```

---

**jQuery docs:**

- `.hasClass()` - http://api.jquery.com/hasClass
- `.addClass()` - http://api.jquery.com/addClass
- `.toggleClass()` - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Comment: +1 This method works particularly well in situation where you are controlling more than a single DOM element. It allows the code to be generalized, and tied specifically to the affected element.

Comment: @Doug - Thanks for the + . You bring up a good point. It could be considered overkill if there's only one element with the behavior. Yours would be more efficient in that case.

Comment: efficient yes... but then if you added an element down the line, mine would have to be rewritten. So it all really depends on the project.

Comment: @andrei - Your images can have several classes. Using `addClass()` and `toggleClass()` simply appends an additional class to the image. The class doesn't need to add any style. It is just used as a flag.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to track whether it has been clicked or not. You can do it a few ways, but since you only have one element you are tracking, a variable is the simplest way to do it. I also optimized your code to utilize chaining. I also changed your selector to be more efficient. `#slide` is better than `img#slide` since an `id` is supposed to be unique:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clicked = false;

  $('#slide')
    .animate({"opacity" : 0.7})
    .hover(function(){
      if(!clicked) {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 1});
      }
    }, function(){
      if(!clicked){
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 0.7});
      }
    })
    .click(function(){
        clicked = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Using a local variable will be more efficient than my answer if there is ultimately only one element to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers in this thread are good, and would work. But for the sake of it here's a different approach.

Based on your code and your question, what you're actually doing is removing the hover behaviour from the element. Which should be done as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('img#slide').animate({"opacity" : .7});

  $('img#slide').hover(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 1});
  }, function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : .7});
  }); 

  $('img#slide').click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('hover');
  });
});
```

Which can be refactored to allow toggling of the behaviour in a novel way:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var over = function(){
   $('img#slide').stop().animate({"opacity" : 1});
  };

  var out = function(){
   $('img#slide').stop().animate({"opacity" : 0.7});
  };

  var on = function(){
   $('img#slide').hover(over, out).one('click', off);
  }

  var off = function(){
   $('img#slide').unbind('hover').one('click', on);
  };

  $("img#slide").one('click', on);

  out.call();

 });
```

Note: I haven't tested this (I'm at work), but you get the idea.